# java string.split function

Tags: java, split

```
Str = "abc|def|ghi^jkl|mno";
String[] Flds = Str.split("[|]"); 
//Flds[0] = "abc";
//Flds[1] = "def";
//Flds[2] = "ghi^jkl";
//Flds[3] = "mno";
```

now I want to know the sub fields for Flds[2], but none of the following are working -

```
String[] Flds = Str.split("[^]");

String[] Flds = Str.split("[^]]");

String[] Flds = Str.split("^");
```

Comment: Ehm, you are trying to split Str again, not Flds[2]

Answer (score 5):

You should be splitting `Flds[2]`

```
String[] subFlds2 = Flds[2].split("\\^");
```

Also, `^` is a reserved character in [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).  You used `[]` to escape `|`, however, `^` also means something inside the `[]` brackets.

Comment: +1 To be more precise `[]` with `^` placed as first character is [Negated Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) for example `[^bc]` means every character besides `b` or `c`.

Answer (score 1):

Double escape the carat:

```
Flds[2].split("\\^")
```

One escape for [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html), then another for the [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Please note:** [**String#split**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29),accepts the parameter which is regular expression:

```
  public String[] split(String regex)
```

`^` is special character in regex, which means beginning of the line. To use it as literal, please use a escape char before it e.g. below:

```
String[] Flds = Str.split("[\\^]");
```

Also I think, it should work fine without braces e.g.

```
String[] Flds = Str.split("\\^");
```

You may find more about regular expression character classes here: [**Regex Char Classes**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html)